# Code-readability of non-loopable initilazations

Tags: java, optimization, code-readability

Imagine you have to initialize some objects that you can't really handle in a loop. On top of calling the constructor, you'll have to init the object somehow with supplied data. Finally you want to also use that object in a different method. For the sake of readability and maybe even computing, would method A or B be recommended?

**Method A**

```
DummyObject a = new DummyObject("fs", "y", 4);
a.init("aseas", true);
otherObjectA.addDummy(a);

DummyObject b = new DummyObject("qwe", "sd", 8);
b.init("a4rhs", true);
otherObjectA.addDummy(b);

DummyObject c = new DummyObject("j", "xe", 39);
c.init("as", false);
otherObjectB.addDummy(c);

DummyObject d = new DummyObject("qw", "k", 12);
d.init("sdfs", true);
otherObjectC.addDummy(d);
// and so on...
```

**Method B**

```
DummyObject a = new DummyObject("fs", "y", 4);
DummyObject b = new DummyObject("qwe", "sd", 8);
DummyObject c = new DummyObject("j", "xe", 39);
DummyObject d = new DummyObject("qw", "k", 12);

a.init("aseas", true);
b.init("a4rhs", true);
c.init("as", false);
d.init("sdfs", true);

otherObjectA.addDummy(b);
otherObjectB.addDummy(c);
otherObjectA.addDummy(a);
otherObjectC.addDummy(d);
// and so on...
```

Comment: and a method `C` could probably be to write a method in order to reduce redundant code

Comment: @KevinEsche True, but that could result in a method requiring a lot of parameters, which will in turn make code very unreadable.

Comment: Look up builder pattern, it makes it more readable. Also the init() method smells for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Why not include the content of init() method in the constructor of DummyObject ? The aim of a constructor is also initialization of the object.

2) If you have good reasons to keep this way and you have many DummyObjects to configure in this way, a more readable solution would be to extract a method to perform initialization and add steps for each DummyObject :

I would use the method A :

```
DummyObject d = new DummyObject("qw", "k", 12);
d.init("sdfs", true);
otherObjectC.addDummy(d);
```

and I would extract a new method like that :

```
  DummyContainer container = ...;
  DummyObject a = new DummyObject("qw", "k", 12);
  initAndAddDummyObject(a, container,"sdfs",true);
     ...
  DummyObject b = new DummyObject("qwe", "sd", 8);
  initAndAddDummyObject(b, container,"a4rhs", true);

     ...

 public void initAndAddDummyObject(DummyObject source, DummyContainer container,  String initString, boolean initBoolean){ 
        source.init(initString, initBoolean);
        container.addDummy(source);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I cant tell you the relationship between these objects and if you could use the Facade pattern to group functionalities together or just an interface. What i can see here is that you can use Factory pattern to create and initialize your objects.

About the code readability it's up to you, what i prefer is Method A.